# Uniform convergence of $f_{n}(x)=\sqrt{nx}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)$ on $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

I want to determine if the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)=\sqrt{nx}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)$ converges uniformly to its pointwise limit on $x>0$. To determine the limit, we can Taylor expand the arctan to find that as $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$, which is correct according to the answer in the text book.

To determine if the convergence is uniform, I want to look at $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x>0}|f_n(x)|$. I started by attempting to take the derivative and find the maxima, but the equation is transcendental, so determining a maximum becomes quite difficult. According to the answer in the book, the convergence is not uniform.

Any help to show this is the case would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $f_n(\frac  1n)=\arctan 1=\frac {\pi} 4$, so the answer is NO, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @geetha290krm Why did you consider $1/n$? Can you elaborate?

Comment: $\sup_{x>0}|f_n(x)|\ge f_n(\frac 1 n)$. Instead of trying to maximize the function it is  a simple natural trick to look to the values at a particular sequence of points .

Comment: In general if $f_n(x)=f(nx)$ and $f\neq 0$ the convergence is not uniform.